# 2 Plots sharing a common and single legend

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have 2 DFs describing 2 objects with 2 factors they have in common. How do I build 2 charts with a single common legend ?

I try with matplotlib subplots, but i dont' understand how works the legend.

```
inport pandas as pd
```

the 1st DF describing Jup :

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'Dates' : pd.date_range('2002-02-04',periods=3),
'fac1' : [1,1.02,0.98],
'fac2':[2,2.05,2.06]
 })
```

the 2d DF describing Tit

```
df2=pd.DataFrame({'Dates' : pd.date_range('2002-02-04',periods=3),
'fac1' : [1,0.95,1.10],
'fac2':[0.5,0.6,0.55]
})
```

I can plot this separately like this :

```
df1.plot(x=df1.iloc[:,0].name,
y=df1.iloc[:,1:3].columns,
legend=True,title='jup')
```

and this :

```
df2.plot(x=df2.iloc[:,0].name,
y=df2.iloc[:,1:3].columns,
legend=True,title='tit')
```

But how do this with a matplotlib style subplots with a common and single legend ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an alternate way to do it. The idea is to create two axis objects and then pass them to plot the two DataFrames. Then use `legend=False` for the first plot as the legends of both the plots are the same. Now you can   set the position of the common legend outside the figure using `loc`.

---

**Complete working answer**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(9, 3))

df1=pd.DataFrame({'Dates' : pd.date_range('2002-02-04',periods=3),
                  'fac1' : [1,1.02,0.98],'fac2':[2,2.05,2.06]})

df2=pd.DataFrame({'Dates' : pd.date_range('2002-02-04',periods=3),
                  'fac1' : [1,0.95,1.10], 'fac2':[0.5,0.6,0.55]}) 

df1.plot(x=df1.iloc[:,0].name, y=df1.iloc[:,1:3].columns, legend=False, title='jup', ax=ax[0])

df2.plot(x=df2.iloc[:,0].name, y=df2.iloc[:,1:3].columns, legend=True, title='tit', ax=ax[1])

ax[1].legend(loc=(1.1, 0.5))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [this recipe from Matplotlib docs](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/figlegend_demo.html). The key is that you need to create your figure and axes first with `subplots` and add your legend to the figure instead of the axes instances:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1) # change layout to (1, 2) for side-by-side plots

l1 = ax1.plot(df1.set_index('Dates'))
l2 = ax2.plot(df2.set_index('Dates'))

fig.legend(l1, ['fac1', 'fac2']) # You only need to add one set of lines and labels

ax1.set_title('jup')
ax2.set_title('tit')
```

Also you only need to set `Dates` as index on the dataframes, and `pandas` and `matplotlib` will handle the rest nicely.

Comment: ok I try. I have an error with your code "inner() got multiple values for argument 'ax'.